# ReuseStrategy in Lucene 4.0

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I'm creating my own analyzer that is based on StopWordAnalyzerBase.

In order to make function AddDocument as it was in 3.0, I need to change ReuseStrategy according to Lucene Documentation. But I don't really understand how to do so, because my analyzer has no methods that allow strategy change.

Answer (score 0):

To change the reuse strategy, you must pass it to the [constructor of the Analyzer class](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/Lucene.Net_4_8_0_beta00016/src/Lucene.Net/Analysis/Analyzer.cs#L83-L94). `StopwordAnalyzerBase` doesn't expose this constructor, so you must subclass `Analyzer` directly and copy anything you need from the `StopwordAnalyzerBase` into your implementation.

You can either use `Analyzer.GLOBAL_REUSE_STRATEGY`, `Analyzer.PER_FIELD_REUSE_STRATEGY`, or subclass `ReuseStrategy` to implement your own logic.